# why is it displaying same result in two rows?

Tags: mysql

Hi I have sql code like that:

```
SELECT vote_id, (SELECT type FROM vote_types WHERE id= 1) AS answer
FROM poll_answers
WHERE question_id =1;
```

and it displays me:

[image]

how to make this question so it can display another answer2 which vote_id = 2 in second row and not displaying answer1 again ?

thanks

Comment: Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: use join othervise explain your question correctly

Comment: @eggyal thanks for that link it gave me some light about it a bit. Anyway I'm still having problems because I did question: SELECT poll_answers.question_id, v.type AS answer FROM poll_answers
JOIN vote_types v ON poll_answers.vote_id = v.id WHERE question_id = 1; but it displays me answers of specified question, in that case question with id 1. I want to print all answers to each question in chosen poll. My poll table is poll_referendum and have columns id and name. How would I do it ? any light ?

Comment: @takeit: Does the `id` column in your `poll_referendum` table relate to the `question_id` in the `poll_answers` table?  If not, how do you determine in which referenda a particular question was asked?

Comment: @eggyal No, the `id` column is not related to the `question_id` in the `poll_answers` table. In `poll_questions` table I have columns `id`, `referendum_id` and `body` and `referendum_id` column from `poll_questions` table is relate to `id` column in `poll_referendum` table. In `poll_answers` table I have columns `id`, `question_id` - (which relate to `id` column in `poll_questions` table) and `vote_id` which relate to `id` column in `vote_types` table.

Comment: @takeit: In that case, you just need to join `poll_questions` to your query too.  See my answer below.

Comment: @eggyal something like `SELECT poll_answers.question_id, v.type AS answer FROM poll_answers
JOIN vote_types v
ON poll_answers.vote_id = v.id
JOIN poll_questions q ON q.id = poll_answers.question_id
WHERE q.referendum_id = 1;` ? I think it works :)

Comment: @takeit: Exactly!  Just like in my answer below.  :)  Grateful if you would [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/161492) and/or [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT poll_questions.id, vote_types.type AS answer
FROM   poll_questions
  JOIN poll_answers ON poll_questions.id    = poll_answers.question_id
  JOIN vote_types   ON poll_answers.vote_id = vote_types.id
WHERE  poll_questions.referendum_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your tables. But I think - 
The query should be

```
SELECT vote_id, type as answer 
    FROM poll_answers, vote_types
    WHERE question_id =1 and question_id = id;
```